# Yii2 best way of dealing with large data with activeDataProvider in GridView?

Tags: mysql, gridview, activerecord, yii2

I have a database table of sales that has 100k records. In the future months the size will double and later triple and etc.. The table has relation with two more tables that I need data from. Finally I want to list everything in GridView with ActiveDataProvider but it takes waaay to long(3-5min). I am wondering what is the best way dealing with this situation?

My current query looks like this:

```
$query = Sale::find()->select([
    's.*',
    'u.username as userName',
    'ship.name as ShipName'
])
  ->joinWith('user')
  ->joinWith('shipping')

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'defaultPageSize' => 25,
            'pageSizeLimit' => 1000],
    ]);
```

As you can see its a simple query, but the data is too huge to work normally.. What can I do?

Comment: My first guess here is you have not indexed the tables properly (if at all). Second guess is you call additional relations in grid that are not eagerly loaded. Third - you keep database on separate server with poor connection to your app. You need to check the Yii 2 logs and SQL logs.

Comment: @Bizley thanks for the comment. 1. You are right I am not indexing tables. 2. Nope no additional relations are caled. 3. Its the same db with pretty good connection. Do you think indexes could drastically improve the query performance?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: just for testing purposes: what is your query runtime, if you remove data from related fields (and joinWith)? 100k rows don't seem too much. if you have primary keys on 'user' and 'shipping' and you NOT use any other fields in where condition, there should not be any noticeable impact on performance. did you mix up db time and rendering time?